# Is there a way to generate an image with more than one colour using the PIL Image module?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, image-generation

I've been using the Image module in PIL in python, and I'm trying to generate an image using an array of hex codes. I have the width of the image set to the number of colours, and I want to create an image where each pixel is a different colour listed in the array. The only issue is, I can't find any examples of this. It seems that the Image module is pretty limited, and I can't use the Choir function, since the number of colours needed isn't set. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Why can't you convert your data to a [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytes) object and then use [Image.frombytes](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.frombytes)?

Comment: Your image is only one row?

Comment: Yep, just one row. I'm generating a palette using the colours from an image, so I only need one pixel per colour.

Comment: Please share your array of hex codes, or if it is more than a few tens of elements just share the first 4-5 and give an indication of how many you have. Use the [edit] button rather than comments. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do using the PIL [`Image.frombytes()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.frombytes) function as @Ture Pålsson suggested. I don't know exactly what format your "array of hex codes" is in, but the following illustrates the basic idea. The format of the data used is 3 bytes-per-pixel RGB.

```
from PIL import Image

data = bytes.fromhex('FF0000 00FF00 0000FF 00FF00 0000FF FF0000 0000FF FF0000 00FF00')
width = len(data) // 3
img = Image.frombuffer("RGB", (width, 1), data, "raw", "RGB", 0, 1)
img.show()
```

Screenshot of result (magnified):

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It's a list, like this: ["#123456", "#123466"], etc. Can I use a list in place of the fromhex function you've used there?

Comment: You can't use a list of strings in that format directly, but you could probably convert it into a list of bytes without too much trouble. Does `"#123456"` represent the 3 byte byte hexadecimal value `0x123456`?

Comment: Just used a dodgy workaround not long ago, thanks. I ended up turning the list into a single string of hex codes and removing the #s. This worked like a treat. Thank you

Comment: You can use [`PIL.ImageColor.getcolor()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageColor.html#PIL.ImageColor.getcolor) to directly convert "#123456" into an RGB value. i.e. `ImageColor.getcolor("#123456", "RGB")` → `(18, 52, 86)`